# Condition check in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I tried assigning value to variable `c` in shell script- the first one works perfectly second one fails with syntax error as below. The only difference being around the '=='.

```
awk: ${12}==W {print $3}
awk:      ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: ${12}==W {print $3}
```

Here is the code I tried:

```
c=`zgrep "600" $present_date$b$a* | awk -F "," '$4==600 {print $3}' | sort | uniq | wc -l`

c=`zgrep "600" $present_date$b$a* | awk -F "," '${12}==W {print $3}' | sort | uniq | wc -l`
```

Can anyone help me please - what is wrong in here.

Some more points:
I have 100s of files each with 38 comma-separated fields.

$present_date$b$a* - picks up all the files based on date. This works fine I know.

I need the count of all the unique 3rd field entries which line contains '600' and and the 12th field= W

Comment: Welcome to SO, `awk` could search strings by itself not need to use `grep` with it, if you could add samples of your input and samples of outputs in your post we could help you more on same. Kindly do add them by using {} button in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the braces around `12` and quote the string you are matching against, like this:

`awk -F "," '$12=="W" {print $3}'`

Answer (score 0):

awk is not shell. awk is a tool with a language all of it's own whose syntax is far more similar to C than to shell. So don't try to use shell syntax like `${variable} == value` in an awk script, use C/awk syntax instead `variable == value`. You don't need sort, uniq, and wc btw - the awk script could do what you want:

```
awk -F',' '($4==600) && ($12=="W") && !seen[$0]++{cnt++} END{print cnt+0}'
```